# rails devise action unknown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, redirect, devise

Hopefully someone can help me with this, my app is working fine.

I can login register and use everything the way it's meant to except. When I open the app and login in I can view the main page of the site.

But if I go to the devise sign in or register page and then click the link for the main page before signing in it just comes up with an error saying

```
Unknown action
The action 'sessions' could not be found for DeviseController
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your link to this

```
<%= link_to "Track", urls_welcome_path %>
```

Comment: In devise view files, check in  session if there is some welcome.html.erb file exists?

Comment: theres no welcome.html.erb in the devise views it's in the views urls directory

Comment: exactly, there's something wrong with that link or your routes

Comment: check your link tag and routes in routes.rb

Comment: wait, this line looks fishy
<%= link_to("Track", :action => 'welcome') %>
run rake routes in your terminal and give me the helper url which looks like url_welcome or something like that, in the above link you have not specified the correct path, which leads to this

Comment: add this link instead <%= link_to "Track", urls_welcome_path  %> and tell me if it works

Comment: haha, it happens brother, please voteup the answer and comment if you found it helpful :)